# Deduced type of auto variable in for statement

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, literals, auto

Considering following code snippet:

```
  for (auto loopcontrol = 0; loopcontrol < 10; loopcontrol++)
  {
     ...
  }
```

How is the type of `loopcontrol` deduced?

On the C++ compiler I use (Microsoft Visual Studio 2017) it is `int`, but why not e.g. `long`?

Is it the type of `0`?

Comment: Yes, it's the type of `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto` deduces the type of the variable from the initialization expression (it is the decayed type of the type of the initializer). In your example the type of `loopcontrol` is the type of `0`. And the type of `0` is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation,

For variables, the type of the auto variable will be deduced from its initializer. Once the type of the initializer has been determined, the compiler determines the type that will replace the keyword auto using the rules for [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) from a function call.

For functions, the return type will be deduced from its return statements (since C++14).

For non-type template parameters, the type will be deduced from the argument (since C++17).